# APC PowerChute management

Tags: ups, electrical-power, apc-smart-ups

I have 3 server with their Smart-UPS connected by USB cable. I downloaded PowerChute B.E. to manage ups. If I well understand PowerChute usage, I have to install an agent for each server and on unique server to centralize management. Is it right?
I tried to do this, but I can add to server only the local ups, other agents/ups are not reachable. May I install a server for every agent?

Comment: If each UPS is connected directly to each server via USB then yes, you need to install the agent on each server. A server can't communicate with a UPS that it doesn't have a connection to (USB, Serial or Network).

Comment: Ok, but can I install 3 agents (1 per server connect by usb to its ups) and only 1 server to connect all agents?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote you have 3 different servers with 3 UPSs. In that situation only way is install PowerChute and recognize local UPS state. You configure them separately.

But if you want, you can use bigger UPS and connect it to all 3 servers. Then you must select main server, you connect signal cable from UPS to this server. You install PowerChute. On other servers you should install PowerChute network. The best way is to consult this with your reseller. Try to find needed information on http://www.apc.com/ website. there you can download all the software  you need. Note some may require additional fees.

For example I found this one that partially describes using UPS with network interface:[APC PowerChute Management](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SFPCNS301&xtmc=powerchute%20comparsion&xtcr=1)

Using the network agent requires a network interface on the UPS.

Question. Your servers has double power unit? If yes, you can connect one to UPS and second directly before UPS to unprotected power. This protects you for UPS malfunction but exposes your hardware to unprotected power.

Comment: No, no, *no*! Never *ever* connect a server directly to unsanitized power like this. This is a very good way to fry a server in a power surge situation.

Comment: I agree with Nathan, I don't think this is a good idea to connect 2nd power source directly. I prefer to cross UPS output (ups1-server1ps1, ups1-server2ps2, ups2-server1ps2, ups2-server2ps1).

Comment: in described situation, there are 3 small upses with 3 separate servers. there is big chance for UPS crash and power down server. this is more chance to accidentaly power down by ups, than damage server by external power. the best is two upses, but small upses are bougth at now. and i think it's no chance to buy another 2 bigger upses. upses are to small for connecting both servers. did you explain another usefull idea? then 'thank you' guys for minuses.